# while using pgfplots package i got error unknown key

Tags: pgfplots

i found the `pgfplots` package installed but i got this error: `unknown key`

if so how can i add the package ?

```
Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.8' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key. \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
```

I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex`. `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`

Comment: Which version of `pgfplots` do you have? (One way of finding out is to compile `\listfiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}a\end{document}` and look in the `.log` file, near the end, where a list of packages is printed.) If you have an older version that could explain the problem. For upgrading: which LaTeX distribution (MikTeX/proTeX, TeX Live, MacTeX,...) do you have?

Comment: @Torbjorn sir i have pgfplots version 1.12.1. is there any possibilities to install the beta version. And i am using windows 10.

Comment: 1.12 is newer than 1.8. Do you need to have `compat=1.8`, or can you remove it, or set a newer version, e.g. `compat=1.12`?

Comment: Sorry sir I am unable to compile same error exists

Comment: The `fillbetween` part (which I forgot to consider earlier), or the `compat` part? Can you reduce your code to the smallest necessary to produce the error, and add that example to your question? Add also the complete content of the `.log` file. (And please stop calling me "sir".)